# Static electricity balloon

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

You know how if two objects are statically charged and put next to each other they will repel each other?

What would happen if you put a negatively charged rod into a balloon with the balloon material also having a negative charge?

Would the two materials repel each other enough for it to stay some what inflated assuming that the rod inside is massless and the balloon has no gas in it?

Would it float?

Also assume that the balloon is in a standard pressure and temperature.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would the two materials repel each other enough for it to stay some
>   what inflated assuming that the rod inside is massless and the balloon
>   has no gas in it?

Yes, it would be somewhat inflated.

> Would it float?

In theory, but I can't imagine any practical system where the charges would "inflate" the balloon nearly large enough to overcome the mass of the object inside.

Consider: try to get a rod to hover over a negatively charged plate.